# Problem related to quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, quadratics

Let $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$ be a quadratic polynomial in which $a$ and $b$ are integers. If for a given $n$ , $f(n)f(n+1) = f(m)$ for some integer $m$ then the value of $m$ is ?

Do we have to substitute $x$ by $n$ and $n+1$ and then multiply it? or is there another method to get the solution because the mentioned process will give an extremely large equation.

Answer is $n(n+1)+an+b$

Comment: I substituted x with n and n+1 in f(x)

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: Please show me how to reach to the answer given in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this quadratic function in factor form:

$$f(x)= (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$ where $x_1,x_2$ are roots of $x^2+ax+b=0$ so $$x_1+x_2 =-a\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;x_1x_2 =b$$

Now $$f(n)f(n+1) = (n-x_1)(n-x_2)(n+1-x_1)(n+1-x_2) =\color{red}{(n-x_1)(n+1-x_2)}\color{blue}{(n+1-x_1)(n-x_2)}$$

Since $$\color{red}{(n-x_1)(n+1-x_2)} = n(n+1)-n(x_1+x_2)+x_1x_2-x_1$$
$$=\underbrace{n(n+1)+na+b}_{=:m}-x_1$$ 
and
$$\color{blue}{(n-x_2)(n+1-x_1)} = n(n+1)-n(x_1+x_2)+x_1x_2-x_2$$
$$=\underbrace{n(n+1)+na+b}_{=m}-x_2$$
So if $m=n(n+1)+na+b$ we have $$f(n)f(n+1)=f(m)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Angle.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a way to simplify it but it seems we have to go brute force anyway.

Examination of highest power terms suggests $m=n(n+1)+...$

Then the difference $f(n)f(n+1)-f(n(n+1))=2an^3+...$

Suggesting again $m=n(n+1)+an+...$

Finally you get to factor $b$ in $f(n(n+1)+an)-f(n)f(n+1)$ to get the final result.

---

An alternative method could be this one, but it seems a bit artificial (knowing the result and all...)

The good thing about it, is that is doesn't require tedious expansions.

$\begin{align}f(n)f(n+1)
&=f(n)^2+f(n)f(n+1)-f(n)^2\\\\
&=f(n)^2+\bigg[f(n+1)-f(n)\bigg]f(n)\\\\
&=f(n)^2+(2n+a+1)f(n)\\\\
&=f(n)^2+2nf(n)+af(n)+\overbrace{f(n)}^{n^2+an+b}\\\\
&=\bigg[f(n)^2+2nf(n)+n^2\bigg]+a\bigg[f(n)+n\bigg]+b\\\\
&=f(f(n)+n)\end{align}$

Thus $m=f(n)+n$

Comment: Isnt there a shorter way to do this sum. I am practising for compititive exams and this process will be way too large and will consume lot of time

Comment: I have searched a bit, but as I said in introduction I wished I could come with some magic, but unfortunately didn't found any real shortcut except the second method I'm exposing but I'm not sure you would find that without already knowing what the result should be... Maybe another poster will be more inspired :p