# Problem related to quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

If $x$ is a real number then what is the greatest value of
  $$ f(x)=2(a-x)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\right)\;\;? $$ 
I cannot figure out how to convert this into a quadratic equation to find out the greatest value of $f(x).$

From what I've read, the answer is given by $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: The expression you describe is not a quadratic polynomial. In fact, it's not a polynomial at all.

Comment: So how do I figure out it's maximum value?

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing your background. For example, do you know calculus? You should edit your post with what you have tried.

Comment: I just know basic calculus. I am still learning it. I have tried to simjplify it  but that seems too long and tedious.

Comment: There is a little problem with quadratic equations. There are usually two roots. In this function $\,f,\,$ the definition has a square root. The maximum sometimes applies if the positive square root is taken, or sometimes the negative square root. These are two different functions, but algebraically they are very similar.

Comment: What is the domain of  $\,a?\,$ Do you allow $\,a<0?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be the largest value of $f$. Then equation $f(x)=M$ has exactly one solution in $x$. This equation is equivalent to:

$$ M-2x(a-x)= 2(a-x)\sqrt{x^2+b^2}$$ after squaring and rearranging and canceling we get:

$$ M^2-2M(ax-x^2)= 4(a-x)^2b^2$$

If $M\ne 2b^2$ then this is quadratic equation in $x$ has discriminant $0$ so...

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem.......

Comment: In my previous asked question I did not get a satisfactory answer. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: Where is that problem? @Wonder

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829686/problem-related-to-quadratic-equations  @Angle

Comment: There is a little problem with this slick solution. What if $\,a=-1,b=1?\,$ The maximum value is $1$ but that is achieved only in the liimit as $\,x\to -\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

If you know some calculus it's probably easiiest to expand the whole equation (writing $\sqrt{x^2+b^2}$ as $(x^2+b^2)^{1/2}$ might help too, as it's easier to then implement the rules of differentiation).

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=2(a-x)(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2})\\
&=2ax+2a(x^2+b^2)^{1/2}-x^2-x(x^2+b^2)^{1/2}\\
\end{align*}

Now find the first derivative $f'(x)$ and set this to zero to find your critical point (or turning point) $x_0$.

Once you have solved $f'(x)=0$, you will need to differentite one more time to get $f''(x)$ and investigate its turning point. To summarise

**First Derivative Test**

Assume that $f'(x_0) = 0$.

**Case $\{+,-\}$** If $f'$ is positive to the left of $x_0$, and negative to the right of $x_0$, then $f$ has a relative maximum at $x_0$.

**Case $\{-,+\}$** If $f'$ is negative to the left of $x_0$, and positive to the right of $x_0$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$.

**Case $\{+,+\}$ and $\{-,-\}$** If $f'$ has the same sign in open intervals around $x_0$, then $f$ has neither a relative minimum or maximum at $x_0$.

**Second Derivative Test for Relative Extrema**

Assume that $f'(x_0) = 0$ and that $f''(x_0)$ exists. Then:

(i) if $f''(x_0)<0$, then $f$ has a relative maximum at $x_0$;

(ii) if $f''(x_0)>0$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$;

(iii) if $f''(x_0)=0$, then $x_0$ can be either a relative maximum, a relative minimum, or a saddle point.

Answer (score 0):

The extremum points of $f$ satisfy $f'(x)=0$. The maximum ones have $f$ increasing on the left and decreasing on the right.

Can you proceed further?

Comment: Is there any other method rather than calculus?

Comment: If you graph the function you can usually tell if and where maximums appear. The specific values for $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ determine the shape of the function and hence where maximums, if any, appear.

Comment: I am trying to find the analyttical way to solve this rather than doing it by a graph and finding the maxima. I need to prove it in analytical way that answer is $a^2+b^2$

Comment: How much analysis do you know? For what values of $x$ is the maximum achieved?

Comment: It is in the chapter of quadratic equations. So I thought that if it could be simplified into a quadratic equation then I could figure out it's maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=2(a-x)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\right)$$
$$f'(x)=2 (a-x) \left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}\right)-2 \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\right)$$ 
$$f'(x)=2(a-x)\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}-2 \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\right)$$
$$f'(x)=2\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\right) \left(\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}-1 \right)$$ So, you need to solve
$$\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}=1\implies \frac{(a-x)^2}{x^2+b^2}=1$$ which makes your quadratic equation which, in fact, is linear
$$\frac{(a-x)^2}{x^2+b^2}=1 \implies (a^2-b^2)-2 a x=0$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

let $\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+x=y,$ then $\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+b^2}-x = \frac{b^2}{y}$ and $\displaystyle 2x=y-\frac{b^2}{y}$

$\displaystyle f(x) = (2a-2x)(x+\sqrt{b^2+y^2}) = (2a-y-\frac{b^2}{y})\cdot y = (2ay-y^2+b^2) $

$f(y)= (a^2+b^2)-(y-b)^2\leq (a^2+b^2)$ equality hold when $y=b$

Comment: `2x=y+b^2/y` That should rather be $\color{red}{-}b^2/y$, and what follows needs fixing, but works nicely otherwise.

Comment: Thanks dxiv.....

Comment: How did you get from $f(x)=2ay-y^2-b^2$ to $f(y)=(a^2+b^2)-(y-b)^2?$

Comment: @Somos That was probably meant to be $\,f(y)=2ay-y^2\color{red}{+}b^2=(a^2+b^2)-(y-\color{red}{a})^2\,$.